# how to create wrapper class so i can show two list data in csv

Tags: class, wrapper-class, csv

Header title show proper but its data not showing in proper format because two repeat i have applied, i want work only with one repeat
this is my class

```
    public with sharing class ExportAsCSVController {

    public List<Document> docList{get; set;}
   // public List<eTMF_Artifact__c> etfList{get;set;}
    public List<eTMF_Artifact__c> folderItemList{get;set;}

    Id folderId;

    public ExportAsCSVController(){
        docList = new List<Document>();
        folderId =  System.currentPagereference().getParameters().get('Id');
        Set<Id> docIdSet = new Set<Id>();
        folderItemList=new list<eTMF_Artifact__c>();
        folderItemList = [Select id,name,Alternate_Names__c,Approval_Status__c,Artifact__c,Artifact_Location__c,Clinical_Site__c,Clinical_Study__c,Content_Type__c,Country__c,Country_Region_Level_Document__c,Date_Signed__c,Dating_Convention__c,Definition_Purpose__c,Description__c,DocumentId__c,Document_Reviewed__c,Document_Status__c,Document_Type__c,Folder__c,ICH_Code__c,Inclusion_Type__c,Investigator_Initiated_Study_Artifacts__c,Protocol__c,Region__c,Section__c,Site_Level_Document__c,SOP_Reference__c,Sponsor_Document__c,Study_ID__c,Translation_Required__c,Trial_Level_Document__c,Type__c,Wet_Ink_Signature__c,Zone__c From eTMF_Artifact__c Where Folder__c = :folderId];

        if(folderItemList.size() > 0){
            for(eTMF_Artifact__c fItem : folderItemList){
                if(fItem.DocumentId__c != null)
                    docIdSet.add(fItem.DocumentId__c);
            }
            if(docIdSet.size() > 0){
                docList = [SELECT Id,Name,Folder.Name,CreatedBy.Name,ContentType,BodyLength,Description,CreatedDate,LastModifiedBy.Name,LastModifiedDate,Author.Name,Type FROM Document Where id IN :docIdSet ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];
                //etfList = [select id,Alternate_Names__c,Approval_Status__c,Artifact__c,Artifact_Location__c,Clinical_Site__c,Clinical_Study__c,Content_Type__c,Country__c,Country_Region_Level_Document__c,Date_Signed__c,Dating_Convention__c,Definition_Purpose__c,Description__c,Document_Reviewed__c,Document_Status__c,Document_Type__c,Folder__c,ICH_Code__c,Inclusion_Type__c,Investigator_Initiated_Study_Artifacts__c,Protocol__c,Region__c,Section__c,Site_Level_Document__c,SOP_Reference__c,Sponsor_Document__c,Study_ID__c,Translation_Required__c,Trial_Level_Document__c,Type__c,Wet_Ink_Signature__c,Zone__c from eTMF_Artifact__c];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is my page

```
<apex:page controller="ExportAsCSVController" cache="true" contentType="text/csv#ExportArtifact.csv" language="en-US">
"Name","Type","Author Name","BodyLength","Description","CreatedBy Name","LastModifiedBy Name","CreatedDate","LastModifiedDate","Alternate Names","Approval Status","Artifact#","Artifact Location","Artifact Name","Clinical Site","Clinical Study","Content Type","Country","Country/ Region Level Document","Date Signed","Dating Convention","Definition / Purpose","Description","DocumentId","Document Reviewed","Document Status","eTMF Folder","ICH Code","Inclusion Type","Investigator Document","Investigator Initiated Study Artifacts","Protocol","Region","Section#","Site Level Document","SOP Reference","Sponsor Document","Study ID","Translation Required","Trial Level Document","Type","Wet Ink Signature","Zone#"
    <apex:repeat value="{!docList}" var="doc">
    "{!doc.Name}","{!doc.Type}","{!doc.Author.Name}","{!doc.BodyLength}","{!doc.Description}","{!doc.CreatedBy.Name}","{!doc.LastModifiedBy.Name}","{!doc.CreatedDate}","{!doc.LastModifiedDate}"
    </apex:repeat>



    <apex:repeat value="{!folderItemList}" var="fol">
    "{!fol.Alternate_Names__c}","{!fol.Approval_Status__c}","{!fol.Artifact__c}","{!fol.Artifact_Location__c}","{!fol.Clinical_Site__c}","{!fol.Clinical_Study__c}","{!fol.Content_Type__c}","{!fol.Country__c}","{!fol.Country_Region_Level_Document__c}","{!fol.Date_Signed__c}","{!fol.Dating_Convention__c}","{!fol.Definition_Purpose__c}","{!fol.Description__c}","{!fol.DocumentId__c}","{!fol.Document_Reviewed__c}","{!fol.Document_Status__c}","{!fol.Document_Type__c}","{!fol.Folder__c}","{!fol.ICH_Code__c}","{!fol.Inclusion_Type__c}","{!fol.Investigator_Initiated_Study_Artifacts__c}","{!fol.Protocol__c}","{!fol.Region__c}","{!fol.Section__c}","{!fol.Site_Level_Document__c}","{!fol.SOP_Reference__c}","{!fol.Sponsor_Document__c}","{!fol.Study_ID__c}","{!fol.Translation_Required__c}","{!fol.Trial_Level_Document__c}","{!fol.Type__c}","{!fol.Wet_Ink_Signature__c}","{!fol.Zone__c}"
    </apex:repeat>


</apex:page>
```

Comment: Can you have multiple documents for single eTMF_Artifact__c? What should happens then?